# Why is $DebugPreference getting lost in a module?

Tags: variables, powershell

I have a powershell script and I have set the `$DebugPreference` to `"Continue"`. However when I call `Write-Debug` from a module that is called from my script, the `$DebugPreference` changed to `"SilentlyContinue"`. Why is that? How can I keep `$DebugPreference` the same as the calling script? Example below

**CallingScript.ps1**

```
$DebugPreference = "Continue"
Write-Host "Debug preference: $DebugPreference"
Write-Debug "Checking that debugging works"
Import-Module Logging;
Write-Log "Debug" "Checking that debugging still works!"
```

**Logging.psm1**

```
Function Write-Log
{
    param (
    [ValidateSet("Error","Warning","Debug","Info")][String]$type,
    [String]$logMessage
    )
    Write-Host "Debug preference: $DebugPreference"
    switch($type)
    {
        "Error" {Write-Error $logMessage;}
        "Warning" {Write-Warning $logMessage;}
        "Debug" {Write-Debug $logMessage;}
        "Info" {Write-Output $logMessage;}

    }
}
```

If I run the script, this is the output:

```
PS > .\CallingScript.ps1
Debug preference: Continue
DEBUG: Checking that debugging works
Debug preference: SilentlyContinue
PS >
```

Comment: This can be explained by the module scope. Have a look to [this answer about that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17112513/608772). Il don't want  to duplicate the answer for nothing. I will do it if it explains your problem.

Comment: @JPBlanc you might have to explain it and show a working example... sorry!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [JPBlanc's link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17112513/608772) in his comment explains: It is a variable scope issue. The module's scope chain goes directly to the global scope and not through any script scopes. Even if it is imported from a script.

[image: module scope]

Your code will work if you set $DebugPreference from your script in the global scope, but of course this has influence on more than just your script.

```
$global:DebugPreference = "Continue"
```

Another solution in this specific $DebugPreference case is to use the -Debug parameter to pass it along. The downside is that you will have to do this with every command you call.

```
Write-Log "Debug" "Checking that debugging still works!" -debug:$DebugPreference
```

A [third solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/06/03/peering-into-script-modules.aspx) would be to set $DebugPreference at the module level.

```
$m = Import-Module Logging -PassThru
& $m {$script:DebugPreference = 'Continue'}
```

Comment: `$script:DebugPreference = "Continue"` seems to work too. I'm still understanding scopes...

Comment: $script:DebugPreference does not work in your script. It may seem that way if you test it after you already changed DebugPreference on the global scope. Start a new powershell and give it a try again.

Comment: I've been reading about scopes. So if my script sets `$script:DebugPreference`, then all called modules will have `$DebugPreference` set to `$script:DebugPreference`. Why should I need to set it at the global scope? I tested in a new Powershell window and it seems to work fine.

Comment: No, I am afraid not. It will only set the variable on the script scope. And more specifically the current script. It has no effect on modules called or loaded from your script. It does have effect on other scripts called from your script, but not different if you didn't specify $script:. It is used to set something on the 'parent' script scope. See http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/02/11/hey-scripting-guy-february-11-2010.aspx If it works for you, thats great, but it does not work for me.